# Пока кнопка нажата, повторять выполнение определенного метода. Как сделать?

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который рисует фигуры, условное название drawImage().
Нужно чтобы при одиночном клике этот метод выполнялся единожды, а при нажатии и удержании повторялся пока удерживается кнопка.
С одиночным кликом все понятно

```
View.OnClickListener onclBtn = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { drawImage(); }
    };
```

Как реализовать многократное повторение при удержании?

Comment: вам нужен onTouchListener() и ловить типы касаний ACTION_DOWN & ACTION_UP

Comment: Это да, но нужна повторяемость, значит нужно выделить поток и его останавливать. Вопрос как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте примерно так

```
    final View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        private Handler mHandler;
        //создаем флаг
        private boolean downWithoutUp = false;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //включаем Handler
                    if (mHandler != null) return true;
                    mHandler = new Handler();
                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.image_id:
                            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);//период удержания после которого сработает Handler в UP (ms)

                            break;

                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //отключаем Handler
                    if (mHandler == null) return true;
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);                      
                    mHandler = null;

                    switch (v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.image_id:
                            if (!downWithoutUp) {//если UP не сработал
                               drawImage();//то вызываем наш метод
                            }

                            break;

                    }
                    downWithoutUp = false;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                downWithoutUp = true;//устанавливаем флагу true, сработал UP
                drawImage();
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 250);
            }
        };

    };
```

Comment: Отлично! Именно то, что нужно. Правда пришлось отключить слушатель на одинарное касание. А можно задействовать и то и то?

Comment: @kaaa: `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` сработает когда вы поднимете палец, это и будет одинарное касание. Другой слушатель ни к чему

Comment: Не получается "кликнуть быстро". Проскакивает два, три нажатия.

Comment: @kaaa: обновил ответ, прочитайте внимательно комментарии

Comment: @kaaa: еще удалил лишний вызов drawImage() в UP

Comment: Все супер! Огромная благодарность!