# Как сделать долгое нажатие кнопки в android studio

Tags: java, android, button, ontouchlistener

Всем привет. Такая задача: нужно реализовать долгое нажатие кнопки. При нажатии должно циклично происходить действие и как только отпускается кнопка, оно должно завершиться.

при использовании .setOnTouchListener и последующих отловах состояния MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN и MotionEvent.ACTION_UP это происходит 1 раз, а если я отловы вставлю в цикл, то бесконечно будет работать.

```
        Button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        boolean OK = true;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            while (OK) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("8");
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    System.out.println("стопэ");
                    OK = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

вот это бесконечно работает.

как сделать так, что бы при нажатии постоянно делалось одно действие, а после отжатия кнопки оно прекращалось?

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762197/190461)

Comment: спасибо, то что надо!

Comment: [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762133/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C/762197#762197) весит ответ на мой вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

Делал я подобную задачу для визиуального счетчика. Нажал кнопку, держишь - и счетчик мотается. Делалось это давно, и не совсем аккуратно, но код был рабочий и выполнял именно то, что вам нужно (по концепции). Это сам листенер:

```
    // event of touch-method for plus and minus buttons
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        when (view) {
            binding.addPage -> {
                incTread = true
                Thread(MyThread(true)).start()
            }
            binding.minusPage -> {
                decTread = true
                Thread(MyThread(false)).start()
            }
        }
    }

    if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        when (view) {
            binding.addPage -> incTread = false
            binding.minusPage -> decTread = false
        }
    }

    if(motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_RELEASE)

    view.performClick()
    return true
}
```

А вот это поток:

```
// additional thread
inner class MyThread(private val increment: Boolean) : Runnable {

    override fun run() {
        if(increment){

            while(incTread) {
                if (book.getCurrentPage() < book.getCountPages()) {
                    book.incCurrentPage()
                    changeBook()
                }else{
                    incTread = false
                }
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }
        }else{
            while(decTread) {
                if (book.getCurrentPage() > 0) {
                    book.decCurrentPage()
                    changeBook()
                }else{
                    decTread = false
                }
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun changeBook(){
        book.setChanged()
        supportBook.updateBook(book)

        // send message to handler in main thread
        val msg = Message()
        msg.obj = "${book.getCurrentPage()}/${book.getCountPages()}"
        handler.sendMessage(msg)
    }
}
```

Это позволяло обрабатывать нажатие сразу двух кнопок: счтечик внизу и счетчик вверх (даже одновременно). Думаю, на его основе вы сможете реализовать свое решение. Еще раз, я не дал готового решения, это лишь возможный путь к нему.

Answer (score 1):

```
down.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    });
```